# CPP to Python using SWIG fails with "error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol"

Tags: python, c++, swig, linkageerror

I am trying to create the simplest cpp-to-python SWIG example.
I have one class (`SwigTest`), consisted of `cpp` and `h` files, with one public method in it `swig_test_connection`.
The swig wrapper generation (`*.cxx` and `*.py` files) works out of the box,
but when I try to build (using `setup.py`) I am getting a linkage error:
`LINK : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol PyInit__swig_test`

**See detailed re-production steps below.**

I followed the instructions from:

- http://www.swig.org/Doc1.3/Python.html
- https://david-estevez.gitbooks.io/tutorial-swig/02_wrapping_simple_c++_library.html
- http://web.mit.edu/svn/src/swig-1.3.25/Examples/python/class/

I feel like I am missing something elementary here, so I will be grateful for any suggestion.

### System details

I am using Windows 10, python 3.6.7 and VS 2019.
I also tried on a clean machine with Windows 10, python 3.6.7 and VS 2017 and got the same results.

### Detailed Reproduce Steps

I created a single class (`SwigTest`) with one public member method in it `swig_test_connection`:

**swig_test.h:**

```
//// swig_test.h ////

#ifndef _SWIG_TEST_
#define _SWIG_TEST_

class SwigTest
{
public:
    int swig_test_connection();
};

#endif // !_SWIG_TEST_
```

**swig_test.cpp:**

```
//// swig_test.cpp ////

#include "swig_test.h"

int SwigTest::swig_test_connection() {
    return 32;
}
```

I also created a `swigtest.i` file:
**swigtest.i**

```
%module swig_test_module
%{
#include "swig_test.h"
%}

%include "swig_test.h"
```

I saved all those files under the same folder:
[image]

Next I created the SWIG wrapping files by running the following command:
`swig -python -c++ swigtest.i`

This generated 2 SWIG wrapper files:

```
swig_test_module.py
swigtest_wrap.cxx
```

The last step was to create `setup.py`:
**setup.py**

```
import os

from distutils.core import setup, Extension


swig_test_module = Extension(
    '_swig_test',
    sources=[
        os.path.join("swigtest_wrap.cxx"),
        os.path.join("swig_test.cpp")
    ]
)

setup(
    name="swig_test",
    version='0.1',
    author="Saar",
    description="""SWIG test""",
    py_modules=["swig_test_module"],
    ext_modules=[swig_test_module]
)
```

Finally, I tried to build the module:
`python setup.py build_ext --inplace`

This generated the following error:

```
LINK : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol PyInit__swig_test
```

Full error stacktrace:

```
running build_ext
building '_swig_test' extension
creating build
creating build\temp.win-amd64-3.6
creating build\temp.win-amd64-3.6\Release
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.26.28801\bin\HostX86\x64\cl.exe /c /nologo /Ox /W3 /GL /DNDEBUG /MT -IC:\Projects\SwigTest\venv\include -IC:\Python367\include -IC:\Python367\include "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft
Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.26.28801\include" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\NETFXSDK\4.8\include\um" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.18362.0\ucrt" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.18362.0\share
d" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.18362.0\um" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.18362.0\winrt" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.18362.0\cppwinrt" /EHsc /Tpswigtest_wrap.cxx /Fobuild\temp.win-amd64-3
.6\Release\swigtest_wrap.obj
swigtest_wrap.cxx
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.26.28801\bin\HostX86\x64\cl.exe /c /nologo /Ox /W3 /GL /DNDEBUG /MT -IC:\Projects\SwigTest\venv\include -IC:\Python367\include -IC:\Python367\include "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft
Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.26.28801\include" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\NETFXSDK\4.8\include\um" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.18362.0\ucrt" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.18362.0\share
d" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.18362.0\um" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.18362.0\winrt" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.18362.0\cppwinrt" /EHsc /Tpswig_test.cpp /Fobuild\temp.win-amd64-3.6\R
elease\swig_test.obj
swig_test.cpp
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.26.28801\bin\HostX86\x64\link.exe /nologo /INCREMENTAL:NO /LTCG /nodefaultlib:libucrt.lib ucrt.lib /DLL /MANIFEST:EMBED,ID=2 /MANIFESTUAC:NO /LIBPATH:C:\Projects\SwigTest\venv\libs /LIBP
ATH:C:\Python367\libs /LIBPATH:C:\Python367 /LIBPATH:C:\Projects\SwigTest\venv\PCbuild\amd64 "/LIBPATH:C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.26.28801\lib\x64" "/LIBPATH:C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\NETFXSDK\4.8\lib\um
\x64" "/LIBPATH:C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\lib\10.0.18362.0\ucrt\x64" "/LIBPATH:C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\lib\10.0.18362.0\um\x64" /EXPORT:PyInit__swig_test build\temp.win-amd64-3.6\Release\swigtest_wrap.obj build\temp.win-amd64-3.6\Release
\swig_test.obj /OUT:C:\Projects\SwigTest\_swig_test.cp36-win_amd64.pyd /IMPLIB:build\temp.win-amd64-3.6\Release\_swig_test.cp36-win_amd64.lib
LINK : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol PyInit__swig_test
build\temp.win-amd64-3.6\Release\_swig_test.cp36-win_amd64.lib : fatal error LNK1120: 1 unresolved externals
error: command 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio\\2019\\Community\\VC\\Tools\\MSVC\\14.26.28801\\bin\\HostX86\\x64\\link.exe' failed with exit status 1120
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated,
Thanks,
Saar

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If someone encounters this issue,
After too much time of debugging, the solution is very simple.

The problem was that the name of the `Extension` declaration didn't match the name in `py_modules` in the `setup` call.

Apparently it should be exactly the same name with leading underscore:

```
import os

from distutils.core import setup, Extension


swig_test_module = Extension(
    '_swig_test_module',
    sources=[
        os.path.join("swigtest_wrap.cxx"),
        os.path.join("swig_test.cpp")
    ]
)

setup(
    name="swig_test",
    version='0.1',
    author="Saar",
    description="""SWIG test""",
    py_modules=["swig_test_module"],
    ext_modules=[swig_test_module]
)
```